# How should I describe a "don't notify of updates until after version X" option?

Tags: user-interface, auto-update

I'm working on some automatic update check code which runs when my app starts up. If there is a new version available, the user can download it or ignore this update.

If the user ignores this update, then the version number of this update is stored in a VersionForUpdateCheck preference. If this preference is set, then future checks will use this to compare against what's available on the server instead of the currently running version.

I don't know how to succinctly label this option in the preferences page. I'm currently going with the cumbersome and unclear "Notify of updates after version [EDITBOX]".

Can you think of a better wording?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I'm not answering your question, and you may have a good reason to ignore me that I don't know about, but.. why even make it visible to the user?

On that preferences page, I would just put:

- The current version
- The latest available version
- An 'Update now' button which is enabled if there's a new version.
- And maybe an 'automatically prompt to update' checkbox

Comment: I like it: Its sort of breaking down one big problem into several small ones, that have already been solved.

Answer (score 2):

How about

[image: Software Updates]
<sub>(source: [rsdn.ru](http://files.rsdn.ru/27808/SoftwareUpdates.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Leave it out of the user preferences entirely. It's confusing and unnecessary, in case you really want to give the user this flexibility, just add either a "don't notify me about this update again" or "please remind me of this update the next time I start" tickbox to the window where the user chooses to ignore the update.

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|  Hi! a new version (1.84) is available for  |
|  upgrade? Should I install it for you?      |
|                                             |
|     () YES     () NO   () Remind me later   |
|                                             |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

If a user ticks NO, don't nag until the next time a newer version is available. Alternatively:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|  Hi! a new version (1.84) is available for  |
|  upgrade? Should I install it for you?      |
|                                             |
|     () YES     () NO                        |
|                                             |
|                                             |
|     () Don't ask about updates until the    |
|        the next version comes out           |
|     () Don't ever ask about updates again   |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

The only thing you'd need in the user preferences would be a "check for updates" box, in case the user clicked "Don't ever ask about updates again."

Comment: I like your dialog example. But I would give the user an option to change his choice at a later point, too. That's what the preferences are for, IMO.

Comment: I don't think it should be a preference, because a.) it's only valid until the next update and not a permanent setting b.) it convolutes the prefs and c.) it could be better handled by an explicit "check for updates". I don't think I'd look for this in the preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like Google Chrome does it. Show updates in Help>About only. And whenever new updates are avaialble, show a button saying 'You have a new version available'

Comment: Chrome is nice because it just silently updates itself. No annoying question boxes asking if you want to update the browser and check for updated plugins, like in Firefox.

Comment: With some programs the user might want to control explicitly when to upgrade (for example I like to have multiple versions of my IDE and JDK around), but in the case of a web browser I don't see any reason why bugfixes and minor updates should not be installed when they are available.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question, is it?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for

> Notify on updates newer than version [version number]

In my opinion, the best approach for preference dialogs is to present a very short description, together with a lengthy explanation of what this option does as a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any valid reason why the user would *not* want to upgrade when a new version of the program is released?

The only cases where I want to have explicit control of the program versions, and even have multiple versions installed concurrently, is with my IDE and compiler, and other development libraries. But software developers are not normal users. With all other programs it would be best to just upgrade the program silently, so that the user never even notices it, just like Google Chrome does.

Maybe in the options there could be an option for prompting when a new version comes available, but the default should be to just upgrade it silently without telling the user (unless it is a major upgrade which is not fully backwards compatible or might break some other stuff).

Comment: I want complete control over whats happening on my computer, so yes: I would want that feature. For my browser, for my IDE, for my graphics editor and every little helper program that I use.

Comment: But the average users (who just browser the net, use email, Word etc.) do not need that kind of control. You are a power user, so you have different needs, which can be accomplished with some custom options (e.g. prompt before upgrading), but the default options should be for the average user.

Comment: Which is why you put it in the preferences page. Those average users never go there anyway.